# Absolute path (external) background image in NodeJS

Tags: css, node.js

```
body {   
 background-image: url("http://opendomain/freeoflicenseimage.jpg");
 background-repeat:repeat;
 background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

This gives an error because it will try to load from http://mywebsite/mypublicrootfolder/http://opendomain/freeoflicenseimage.jpg

Any approach that doesn't require messing with the server routes?

Comment: If it's actually trying to load from that double URL, then there's something wrong with your server routes designed to serve the image.  You will have to show us your server code for us to make a suggestion on how to fix.  There is nothing wrong with the client-side code you show and nothing in the HTML that would cause a double URL.

Comment: You're wrong, it's Node.Js/express causing this.